# Best way to report the growth of a file using powershell?

Tags: powershell, compare, report, powershell-3.0

I would like to report the database size to myself via email every week and make a comparison to the week before and display the growth in Megabyte and/or %.
I have everything besides the comparison done.

Imagine this setup :

- SQL server with 100 databases

Now there are plenty of ways to do a comparison, I thought about writing the sizes into XML by powershell and later read out using a second script and report to me.

Since I trained myself in powershell I might have gaps here, so I am afraid to miss an easy way.

Does anyone has a nice Idea of how to compare the size?

The report and calculation I will manage myself later, I just need a good way to do that.

Currently I am on Powershell 3.0 but I can upgrade to 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't invent the wheel again. Sql Server already has tools to monitor DB file sizes. So does Performance Monitor. There are several 3rd party products available too. Ask your local DBA if there already is such a system present.

A common practice is to query the server for DB file sizes on, say, daily basis and store it in utility db table with timestamp. Calculating change volumes, ratios and whatnot can be done on TSQL side. (Not that it is CPU intensive anyway.)

Comment: that's what I ment by : "so I am afraid to miss an easy way" - I also wanted to practice more powershell of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would creat foreach database an csv file. then write out two rows:
Date,Size
27.08.2014,1024
28.08.2014,1040
29.08.2014,1080

Then you can import the csv file, sort the row by date, compare the last two sizes and send the result by mail.